# Missing browser app causing crash for XML action.VIEW Intent

Tags: android

Given the following preference header XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<preference-headers xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <header
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_public_white_36dp"
        android:title="@string/menu_website" >
        <intent
            android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:data="http://www.example.com" />
    </header>

</preference-headers>
```

What would be the best way of mitigating this error:

```
Fatal Exception: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://www.example.com }
```

The issue being that if the user device does not have a browser installed, they will crash with that error.

Additionally, Amazon TV devices will also crash (as they have no browser) with their own variety of no-browser exception.

Normally, you could check for the existence of receiver for this Intent, or simply catch the exception. With XML it is more difficult. Is the only way of preventing this to check the device in the `PreferenceActivity` in order to remove this header for "bad" devices?

Answer (score 0):

My current answer to this situation. Hoping for a more general solution.

```
@Override
public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
    loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.preference_headers, target);

    if(Utils.isAmazonTV() || !Utils.canHandleWebsite(this)) {
        Iterator<Header> it = target.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            Header header = it.next();
            if(header.id == R.id.preference_website) {
                it.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on your own answer I opted to do something slightly more refined.

```
@Override
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
    loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.pref_headers, target);
    Iterator<Header> it = target.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Header header = it.next();
        if (header.id == R.id.id_of_header) {

            //Website Intent
            String url = "http://www.yoururl.com";
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            browserIntent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
            if (browserIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
                header.intent = browserIntent;
            } else {
                it.remove();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It is a nice idea - if you want to link to the current Apps market page. I assume you made a "rate this app" settings row? However it doesn't help if you are just providing a link to a website. It will first attempt to create a link to the market for the current App (which is entirely against the question intent)! However, the answer is sound and more feature complete than mine. If you make the current code an additional example, and make another example above that more accurately represents the question I will happily accept this answer.